# Filter DataList through TextBox and DropDownList Getting Nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing an application where i want to add search, i'm using a DataList on my page and want to filter this. I did my but blank page is showed when i clicked over the search button.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string coom = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["COMM"].ConnectionString;
    string q = "select * from Place where Name Like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' AND Comments Like '%" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "%'";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(coom);
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, connection);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    DataList1.DataSource = ds;
    DataList1.DataBind();
}
```

I'm stuffing for 3 hours but do not where is the problem.

Any help please! thanks

Comment: Did you debug and check if query is returning any data or not? Are you binding DataList to any datasource in the Page_Load ?

Comment: Thanks #Chetan_Ranparya !

Answer (score 0):

Try debug your `TextBox1.Text`, `DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text` have value or not, run at SQL your string command with value you get from `TextBox1.Text` and `DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text`. If it have record return, check your `DataSet`.